# Maintaining distance in Shorinji Kempo's Tenchiken Dai Ichi Hokai

Tags: shorinji-kempo

When performing the Hokai (pair form) Drills of Shorinji Kempo we are often taught that the two kenshi should remain along the same line on which they began.

Is this possible to do correctly if the two kenshi are of different reaches/heights?  I would have thought that because the Kihon Ma'ai (optimal striking distance) for a kick from a taller person is much greater than the Kihon Ma'ai for the punch from a shorter person this Hokai could not be performed correctly on a line at all in this situation.

That said I have seen instructors criticise kenshi who end the Hokai clockwise or anticlockwise of their starting position.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the idea of Shu Ha Ri could come into play for this.
Shu (learning and practice of basics) Ha (progress of the techniques sticking to basics)and Ri (keeping the basic but learn to adjust to your size and your Kenshi's
size to work to together ( Hito) to reach a higher level together while training. A good example of this is when working together in a Embu. Sometimes for a technique to work on someone who is maybe bigger or smaller heavy or light...maybe double jointed (when doing Juho)ECT... as long as you stick to the basic fundamentals you make adjustments to have the technique work close to the way it was taught. The lines you and your partner start with should finish close to the area for the Embu to look good , lets say for a demo purpose.
Thank you Kenshi Vince Faiella Ni Dan
NYC DOJO Sensei Miyata 28 years

Comment: I understand that it's not a simple thing to do in the first place.  But if the Kenshi have say a 10" difference in their heights is it possible?  IE. If you are both adjusting correctly for the height difference will you not naturally end up with one kenshi moving more than the other in a clockwise or anticlockwise direction?

Comment: Also Embu is very much a new addition to Shorinji Kempo.  The founder Kaiso didn't introduce this idea.  So would he have wanted the techniques done this way?  Or is this a new development?